# Select records with more populated fields

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have 2 records in my database like so:

```
id | name      | photos

1  | test name | http://www.photo.com/1.jpg

2  | test name | null
```

These 2 records are the same except 1 has a photo and the other one does not.  I can de-dupe this while doing a select with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'test name' GROUP BY name;
```

This gives me 1 single record but I want to return the row WITH a photo.  What can I do to this query to achieve that?

Note: I can not just assume that at least 1 of the duplicates will have photos. Sometimes they both might be null so I can not use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'test name' AND photos IS NOT NULL GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, max(photos) as photos
FROM table 
GROUP BY name;
```